# Error happened while using Jenkins to push docker image

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'd like to push the image `image/name` to the docker repository `image/name` through Jenkins. I have logged in my docker account on my local machine. But it returned with the error:

```
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerClientException: Could not push image: errors:
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
unauthorized: authentication required
```

why?

Comment: It's not clear what's Jenkins related here since you mentioned you use a local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the library you are building with to pass credentials

From the doc:

```
    .withRegistryUsername(registryUser)
    .withRegistryPassword(registryPass)
```

Reference: https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md

I'm assuming this is the library you use by the error message you posted.